# Framework for PEPS of Surface Code

Tags: simulation, surface-code, tensor-networks

I am reading [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06460) about the implementation of Surface Code with noise in PEPS tensor network.

1. I am looking for a **framework**/library (preferred python) that is the nearest for such an implementation, any suggestions?
2. Why is this method not very **common**?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I saw that Prof. David Poulin who led this idea in this article, and was generally a great inspiration, died young from cancer, in 2020, at age 43. This might be one of the reasons it did not continue so much. Andrew Darmawan that wrote the article actually plans to continue research in this field.
2. Grate library for tensor networks, is [This one of Google](https://github.com/google/TensorNetwork). I used [the manual on page 42](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aa6dc3) that is provided in the Git introduction inside, to build a small PEPS simulation of surface code, which, from the definition of its stabilizer, is an equal superposition of all closed circles, and therefore each tensor is defined as one that allows even amount of edges:

[image: each tensor is defined as one that allows even amount of edges]

Using the following code, it was very simple to build the whole surface:

```
import numpy as np
import tensornetwork as tn
from itertools import product

Z = np.matrix([[1,0],[0,-1]])
X = np.matrix([[0,1],[1,0]])

def create_SurfaceCode_Node(x,y):
    '''Build the Surface Code Node tensor'''
    A = np.zeros([2 for _ in range(8)])
    
    for l,d,r,u in product(range(2), repeat=4):
        A[l][(l+d)%2][d][(d+r)%2][r][(r+u)%2][u][(u+l)%2] = 1
    mps_node = tn.Node( A , axis_names=['l', 'l+d','d','d+r','r','r+u','u','u+l'],name='('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
    
    return mps_node

def create_Surface(w,h):

    # NODES
    boundary_node = {}
    surface_nodes = {}
    for y in range(h):
        for x in range(w):
            
            # Only releveant in even places
            if (x+y)%2==0:
                
                # Internal Nodes
                surface_nodes[(x,y)]=create_SurfaceCode_Node(x,y)
                
                # Boundary
                if y==0:
                    if x==0:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'r+u')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: r+u ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'u+l')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: u+l ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'l+d')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: l+d ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                    elif x==w-1:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'d+r')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: d+r ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'r+u')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: r+u ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'u+l')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: u+l ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                    else:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'r+u')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: r+u ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'u+l')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: u+l ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                elif y==h-1:
                    if x==0:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'u+l')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: u+l ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'l+d')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: l+d ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'d+r')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: d+r ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                    elif x==w-1:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'l+d')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: l+d ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'d+r')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: d+r ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'r+u')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: r+u ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                    else:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'l+d')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: l+d ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'d+r')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: d+r ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                else:
                    if x==0:
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'u+l')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: u+l ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'l+d')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: l+d ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                    elif x==w-1: 
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'d+r')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]), name='B: d+r ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
                        boundary_node[(x,y,'r+u')] = tn.Node( np.array([1,0]) ,name='B: r+u ('+str(x)+','+str(y)+')')
    
    # CONNS
    connected_edges=[]
    
    # Internal Conn
    for y in range(h-1):
        for x in range(w):
            if (x+y)%2==0:
                # Internal Conn
                if (x-1)>=0:
                    conn=surface_nodes[(x,y)]['l+d']^surface_nodes[(x-1,y+1)]['r+u']
                    connected_edges.append(conn)
                if (x+1)<=w-1:
                    conn=surface_nodes[(x,y)]['d+r']^surface_nodes[(x+1,y+1)]['u+l']
                    connected_edges.append(conn)   
                
    for key in boundary_node:
        conn = boundary_node[key][0] ^ surface_nodes[(key[0],key[1])][key[2]] 
        connected_edges.append(conn)          
    
    return surface_nodes,connected_edges

## Script 
d=2
w=d
h=d
surface_nodes,connected_edges = create_Surface(w,h)
# print((connected_edges))

#####################################################

nodes = tn.reachable(surface_nodes[(0,0)])

output_edge_order1=[]

for key in surface_nodes:
    if surface_nodes[key].name[0] != 'B':
        for side in ['l','d','r','u']:
            output_edge_order1=output_edge_order1+[surface_nodes[key][side]]
            
result = tn.contractors.greedy(nodes,output_edge_order=output_edge_order1)


for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h in product(range(2), repeat=8):
    if result.tensor[a][b][c][d][e][f][g][h] != 0:
        print((str(result.tensor[a][b][c][d][e][f][g][h]) + "|"  + str([a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]) + ">+"))
```

Resulted in this case in all 4 possible circles (no circle, 2 circles, 1 circle, 1 other circle):

```
1.0|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]>+
1.0|[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]>+
1.0|[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]>+
1.0|[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]>+
```

Here is an example of how it looks in one of the combinations, in the case of a bigger rectangle:
[image: example for how it looks in one of the combinations, in case of a bigger rectangle]